# Jquery Datatables filter (like 'where' clause) same JS Data for every table on same page

Tags: ajax, datatables

I'd like to share the same data source (`JSON` Javascript variable) between multiple tables on the same page, each one filtered like this:

include only data from data source where column 'id' == table html attribute 'id'

Without implementing `AJAX` calls, is it possible to filter out JS source data in realtime from within datatable function (being able to access external data attribute)?

This is my actual code:

```
var $tabella = $('table.tabellaDanno').DataTable({      
        "data": dannoRelazioneJs,
        "info": false,
        "paging": false,
        "searching": false,
        "columns": [
            {
                "data": "descrizione",
                "render": function(data) {
                    return "<div contentEditable=\"true\">" + data + "</div>";
                }
            },
            {"data": "um"},
            {"data": "quantita"},
            {"data": "costoUnitario"},
            {"data": "totaleNuovo"},
            {"data": "statoUso"},
            {"data": "totaleUso"},
            {
                "data": null,
                "render": function(data) {
                    return "<a class=\"btn btn-danger\" name=\"eliminaRigaDanno\" title=\"Elimina Danno\" id=\""+data.id+"\"><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-minus-sign\"></span></a>"
                }
            }
        ]

    })
```

Thank you for reading,
Alex

Comment: you can try my yadcf plugin, try using the [initMultipleTables](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L328) , see [it in action](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/dom_multi_columns_tables_1.10.html)

Answer (score 1):

> **SOLUTION**

Use [custom filters](http://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) to filter data using your own rules.

> DataTables provide an API method to add your own search functions, `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search`. This is an array of functions (push your own onto it) which will will be run at table draw time to see if a particular row should be included or not.

Please note that despite data being array of objects, inside custom filtering function data is represented by array, so in the example below column ID is retrieved by using `data[0]`. Use appropriate zero-based index if your ID is in column other than first.

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
        var api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api( settings );        

        // Table ID
        var tableId = api.table().node().id;

        // Column ID
        var colId = data[0];

        return ((tableId === colId) ? true : false);
    }
);

$(document).ready(function (){        
    var data = [
        { "id": "table1","name": "Tiger Nixon","position": "System Architect","salary": "$320,800","start_date": "2011\/04\/25","office": "Edinburgh","extn": "5421"},
        { "id": "table2","name": "Garrett Winters","position": "Accountant","salary": "$170,750","start_date": "2011\/07\/25","office": "Tokyo","extn": "8422" }
    ];

    var table = $(".dt").DataTable({
        data: data,
        columns: [
            { "data": "id" },           
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "extn" },
            { "data": "start_date" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ]        
    });
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g20049n9/1/) for code and demonstration.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand where you are heading. Lets say you have multiple tables like this, with a "*html attribute 'id'*" :

```
<table data-id="1"></table>
<table data-id="2"></table>
```

and a shared JSON variable

```
var data = [
    { "id" : 1, "someOtherValue" : "joe" },
    { "id" : 1, "someOtherValue" : "ben" },
    { "id" : 2, "someOtherValue" : "gary" },
    { "id" : 2, "someOtherValue" : "peter" },
    { "id" : 2, "someOtherValue" : "john" },
    { "id" : 1, "someOtherValue" : "fritz" },
    { "id" : 1, "someOtherValue" : "carl" }
]
```

then you can initialise all tables in once like this

```
$("table").each(function() {
    $table = $(this);
    $table.DataTable({
        data : dataFilter($table.data('id')),
        columns : [
            { data : 'id', title : 'id' },
            { data : 'someOtherValue', title : 'A value' }
        ]
    })
})
```

using this function as `dataFilter()` :

```
function dataFilter(val) {
    var result = [], i;
    for (i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        if (data[i].id == val) result.push(data[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/wbod677n/**

That is the principle. This is of course not exactly what you are trying to do, replace `data-id` (or what ever you call the attribute) with the value you have in mind, so it correspond to what ever value in your shared JSON.